# Accidentally changed owner of `/etc/sudoers` to non root. Can't sudo or revert

Tags: linux, permissions, raspberry-pi, sudo, raspbian

On Raspbian, tried to change permission for `/etc/sudoers.d/octoprint-shutdown` to `pi` user to edit the file and it worked but now I can't `sudo` anything.

The command I used to break it:
`pkexec chown pi:pi /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.d -R`

And my failed attempts at trying to repair it:

```
pi@fluidd:~ $ pkexec chown root:root /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.d -R
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.policykit.exec ===
Authentication is needed to run `/usr/bin/chown' as the super user
Authenticating as: ,,, (pi)
Password:
polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

pi@fluidd:~ $ sudo -i
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 1000, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: error initializing audit plugin sudoers_audit

pi@fluidd:~ $ su -
Password:
su: Authentication failure
```

It seeems like Raspbian by default is configured so that the root account can't be logged into using a password so I'm a little lost as to how to go about it. Thanks!

Comment: You'll likely need to fix this from a live environment. You can mount the sd card on a different machine and adjust the permissions from there.

Comment: This worked like charm. I was able to mount SD on Ubuntu. Did `cd /media/[user]/rootfs/etc` then `sudo chown -R root:root sudoers sudoers.d` & `sudo chmod 440 sudoers` did the trick! Thanks a lot. I can mark as answered if you want to convert comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll likely need to fix this from a live environment. You can mount the sd card on a different machine and adjust the permissions from there.